# How do I check how many (sub)kernels my program is using?

Tags: kernel

I am running a code that uses up to 60% of CPU on my quad-core machine, suggesting that it is using some subkernel, introducing overhead in the computations and slowing down the program which is not optimized for parallel computing.

How do I check how many subkernels are currently running?

How do I tell Mathemtatica not to use any subkernel?

I use Mathematica 11.3 on a windows 10 64bit machine

Comment: Computing subkernels launch when you run either `LaunchKernels[]` or run some `Parallel*[]` functionality. You can see any subkernel processes from within Windows Task Manager.